# Matlab - Iterating through an array and appending to a new one

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, simulink

I got an array that is a audio recording, and I'd like to add some noise on it so later I can remove it in Simulink and compare the original to the one that I removed the noise.

My problem is that I'm pretty new to Matlab's languages/functions, so I got stucked in a for loop that I didnt understand how It works properly in Matlab.

I got this huge array (voice recorded):

```
voice = [0.0012    0.0012;
         0.0003    0.0005;
         (....)    (....);]
```

And what I'd like to do is to add some values to each line, so it will be noisy (another array):

```
noise = [0.0142    0.0143]
```

To do It I would do line by line in python with a pseudo code like this:

```
new_audio = []
for line in voice:
    new_line = (line+noise)
    new_audio.append(new_line)
```

I need to keep the original so I can compare later. Could you guys give me a hand on it? I'd love to know how to make it happen in Matlab.

Obs: (This is also me trying to update an oldcode from my teacher so It works in new Matlab for other students)

Comment: so is the size of `noise` 1x2 or rather the same size as `voice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is just create a new array from the old one and add the noise. If you want to add `[0.0142, 0.0142]` to every row, then use `bsxfun` to broadcast the operation to each row.

```
noisy = bsxfun(@plus, voice, [0.0142, 0.0142]);
```

What I think that you *actually* want though is *different* noise for each sample of your data. To do this, then just create your matrix of noise and add it to your original data.

```
% Create some random noise
noise = rand(size(voice)) - 0.5;

% Add this to your original signal
noisy = voice + noise;
```

In general, there are two things to remember when working with MATLAB as opposed to python: 1) for loops tend to be pretty costly and 2) constantly appending data to an array is *very* costly because the data has to be re-allocated every time since all array elements are stored in contiguous memory. So if you find yourself doing something like:

```
for thing in things:
    other_thing.append(thing)
```

In MATLAB this would typically be a matrix operation rather than a for loop that changes the size of `other_thing` with each iteration.

Comment: It isn't exatly this values that I mentioned, there's a big formula behind, but that's the idea. Thanks, that solved my question without needing to iterating several minutes on the array. I used the bsxfun to add it.

Comment: Simply add the noise to the voice doesnt work, becouse the voice is a 33000x2 array and the noise is 1x2.

Comment: @ArthurSilva Please look at my first example if you want to add the *same* two values to everything. The example using `bsxfun` and replace the `[0.0142, 0.0142]` with your variable.

Answer (score 1):

I like Daniel's solution, however there are some edits needed:

```
new_audio = voice;
new_audio(:,1) = new_audio(:,1) + noise(1);
new_audio(:,2) = new_audio(:,2) + noise(2);
```

Here is an alternative way to accomplish the same end:

```
voice = [0.0012, 0.0012;0.0003, 0.0005; 0.0025, 0.0100];
noise = [0.0142,0.0142];
dim1Size = size(voice,1);
dim2Size = size(voice,2);
voiceWithNoise = zeros(dim1Size,dim2Size);
for dim1Idx = 1:dim1Size
   voiceWithNoise(dim1Idx,:) = voice(dim1Idx,:)+noise; 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a copy of voice and add the values:

```
new_audio = voice
new_audio(:, 3) = noise(1)
new_audio(:, 4) = noise(2)
```